# Rails controller test error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

I'am making a controller test, but I have this error. My model tests passing, but about this I don't know what is going on:

```
/cook-book/test/controllers/recipes_controller_test.rb:23]:  "Recipe.count" didn't change by 1 Expected: 3 Actual: 2
```

my 'recipes_controller_test.rb':

```
require 'test_helper'

class RecipesControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  include Devise::TestHelpers
    setup do
       @recipe = recipes(:one)
       user = User.create!(email: "example2@test.com", password:      "password",password_confirmation: "password" )
       sign_in user
    end  
   ....
  test "should create recipe" do
    assert_difference('Recipe.count') do
      post :create, recipe: { title: @recipe.title, image_file_name: @recipe.image_file_name, ingredients: @recipe.ingredients, description: @recipe.description } 
      end

    assert_redirected_to recipe_path(assigns(:recipe))
   end
```

'recipes.yml':

```
one:
 title: MyString
 image_file_name: Myimage
 ingredients: MyText
 description: MyText

two:
 title: MyString
 image_file_name: Myimage
 ingredients: MyText
 description: MyText
```

and recipe model:

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments
  has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "400x400#", small: "250x250#"}
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
  validates :title, presence: true, length: { maximum: 30 }
  validates :ingredients, presence: true
  validates :description, presence: true
  validates :image, presence: true
  searchkick
end
```

@Edit

my 'recipe_controller'

```
Class RecipesController < ApplicationController
before_action :find_recipe, only: [ :show, :edit, :update, :destroy ]
before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]
.....

def create
    @recipe = current_user.recipes.build(recipe_params)

    if @recipe.save
        redirect_to @recipe
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end
private

def find_recipe
    @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id])
end

def recipe_params
    params.require(:recipe).permit(:title, :ingredients, :description, :image, :category_id)
end
```

Thanks!

Comment: Comment out the whole `assert_difference` (leaving `post` part) and check whether second test   passes - your controller can do some stuff in a before filter like redirecting you to login page.

Comment: I commented out, ran test and I get this     'ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches     {:action=>"show", :controller=>"recipes", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]
    test/controllers/recipes_controller_test.rb:27:in `block in <class:RecipesControllerTest>''

Comment: In that case please show your controller create action - It seems you are not checking whether save was successful and you have validation errors with your test data.

Comment: Ok, I added it to my question

Comment: try `raise assigns(:recipe).errors.inspect` after the post.

Comment: RuntimeError: #<ActiveModel::Errors:0x0000000713c4a8 @base=#<Recipe id: nil, title: "MyString", ingredients: "MyText", description: "MyText", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, user_id: 3, image_file_name: nil, image_content_type: nil, image_file_size: nil, image_updated_at: nil, category_id: nil>, @messages={:image=>["can't be blank"], :category_id=>[], :title=>[], :ingredients=>[], :description=>[]}>

Comment: Here we are, image is empty. In paperclip it is not enough to specify image name for image to be present, you actually need to give it a file. It might a pain, so it might be a better idea to stub paperclip method. Here is a good blog entry on that subject: http://natashatherobot.com/stub-paperclip-has_attached_file-rspec/